# OPC UA, how do I interact with a loaded .NodeSet2.xml file

Tags: c#, opc-ua, opc

I am using the Traeger OPC UA toolkit C# server samples, (specifically project "Server.NodeSet.Umati.MachineTool") which demonstrate how to load a NodeSet2 XML file (specifically the Machine Vision "Opc.Ua.MachineVision.NodeSet2.xml" file).

My problem is that the sample does not demonstrate how to connect to the loaded XML node description. How do I locate a node and then, read and write node values, respond to methods read and write input and output parameters, and raise events, etc. Can anybody give me a simple sample that demonstrates these basic interactions.